# Use Step Function to run Glue Job in a different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

Is it possible to run the Glue Job from Step Function in the different accounts?

There is the official doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-glue.html how to run Glue Job from Step Function, but it doesn't say anything about cross-account execution.

Is it possible to do this? If not, then what the best way to call Glue Job from Step Function in a different account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Step Functions now supports Cross Account service integrations including for Glue. See the docs here for more info:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-access-cross-acct-resources.html

This blog post from the launch may help as well.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-cross-account-access-capabilities-for-aws-step-functions/